# Sharing swap partition between Ubuntu and Kali

Tags: linux, dual-boot, swap

I am making a fresh install dual-boot for kali and ubuntu. I had this question in my mind if I will create a swap-area of 32GB (16 Gb RAM) will it work for both the Linux distro?

Answer (score 3):

It will work, but you won't be able to hibernate the system (a.k.a. suspend to disk) as the current system state is saved to a swap partition. You could overcome this problem by hibernating into a swap file, that would require tweaking of kernel parameters.

Comment: Means it will lead to conflicts. So, I think I will create a separate swap area for kali and ubuntu